# How implement the mediation ad in android

Tags: android, admob

I implement the mediation ad in android but it is not showing i use currently AdMob House Ads and Hunt Mobile Ads in Ad Network Mediation.

i implement both the xml and java coding way but neither work for me.

my xml code

```
 <com.google.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
        android:id="@+id/ad"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="6cd435789dcc43c0"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" />
```

and the log cat error is

```
01-23 19:13:10.079: E/Ads(1771): Cannot find adapter class 'com.huntmads.admobadaptor.HuntMadsAdapter'. Did you link the ad network's mediation adapter? Skipping ad network.
01-23 19:13:10.079: E/Ads(1771): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.huntmads.admobadaptor.HuntMadsAdapter
01-23 19:13:10.079: E/Ads(1771):    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
01-23 19:13:10.079: E/Ads(1771):    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:217)
01-23 19:13:10.079: E/Ads(1771):    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:172)
01-23 19:13:10.079: E/Ads(1771):    at com.google.ads.g.a(SourceFile:133)
01-23 19:13:10.079: E/Ads(1771):    at com.google.ads.i.run(SourceFile:116)
01-23 19:13:10.079: E/Ads(1771):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
01-23 19:13:10.079: E/Ads(1771):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-23 19:13:10.079: E/Ads(1771):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-23 19:13:10.079: E/Ads(1771):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
01-23 19:13:10.079: E/Ads(1771):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-23 19:13:10.079: E/Ads(1771):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-23 19:13:10.079: E/Ads(1771):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
01-23 19:13:10.079: E/Ads(1771):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
01-23 19:13:10.079: E/Ads(1771):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-23 19:13:10.079: E/Ads(1771): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/huntmads/admobadaptor/HuntMadsAdapter
01-23 19:13:10.079: E/Ads(1771):    ... 14 more
01-23 19:13:10.079: E/Ads(1771): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.huntmads.admobadaptor.HuntMadsAdapter
01-23 19:13:10.079: E/Ads(1771):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
01-23 19:13:10.079: E/Ads(1771):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
01-23 19:13:10.079: E/Ads(1771):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
01-23 19:13:10.079: E/Ads(1771):    ... 14 more
```

Comment: Did you add the appropriate .jar file to the lib folder?

Comment: yes i added GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.2.1.jar in my libs folder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you have the Admob package downloaded, but you need to also download the .jar file for the other types of ads. Google provides [instructions](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/ad-network-mediation) for all mediated ads, and the specific download link for the [Huntmads jar](http://sharing.huntmads.com/SDK/admob/Android/huntmadsadaptor.zip).

Comment: i also added huntMads.jar but happen it giving continue this error.

Comment: Hmmm... Try re-building the entire app. Also, make sure it was included in the right folder (/libs)

Comment: yes i added all the necessary jar in the libs folder but the problem is not solving